# Using strip() to clean up a string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am new to python and I have a string that looks like this

`Temp = "', '/1412311.2121\n`"

my desired output is just getting the numbers and decimal itself.. so im looking for

```
1412311.2121
```

as the output.. trying to get rid of the ', '/\n in the string.. I have tried Temp.strip("\n") and Temp.rstrip("\n") for trying to remove \n but i still seems to remain in my string. :/... Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 18):

Strings are immutable. `string.strip()` doesn't change `string`,  it's a function that returns a value.  You need to do:

```
Temp = Temp.strip()
```

Note also that calling `strip()` without any parameters causes it to remove all whitespace characters,  including `\n`

As stalk said, you can achieve your desired result by calling `strip("',/\n")` on `Temp`.

Comment: As for strip, `Temp = Temp.strip("', /\n")` work for mentioned example

Answer (score 6):

If the data are like you show, numbers that are wrapped from right and left with non-number data, you can use a very simple regular expression:

```
g = re.search('[0-9.]+', s)  # capture the inner number only
print g.group(0)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use a regular expression to do this:

```
In [8]: s = "', '/1412311.2121\n"

In [9]: re.findall(r'([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]\d+)?)', s)
Out[9]: ['1412311.2121']
```

This returns a list of all floating-point numbers found in the string.

Comment: He's new. Might want to remove the interpreter stuff, and include the `import re`.

Also, that regex is pretty advanced for a new user.